# Nifi testing : Input Port and Output Port

Tags: testing, input, port, apache-nifi

I have a flow with one input and 2 output flows (happy path and failure path). I would like to test the flow, thinking to put message directly to the input flow and validate the output flows. Possible options are to use REST api or site-2-site with transaction ?. I managed to get to use site-to-site for write and read but i have noticed that output port is left with message even after consuming it (i did commit the transaction i.e .
transaction.confirm() & transaction.complete()).

Anyone managed to get this working and can share the sample code ? please or any other way to test this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting this flow into a process group and on the root (or ancestor process group) canvas, use a `GenerateFlowFile` processor to generate test fixture data and route this to the PG input port. Then use one or more `LogAttribute` processors to consume the success/failure output and verify it. This ad-hoc test harness will make refining your flow much easier.

Comment: Hi Andy - Thanks for that. That is a valid suggestion but the problem with GenerateFlowFile is that this allows only single data to pass. I could have many GenerateFlowFiles to cover all the scenarios but that looks ugly. If I can get port test working, then i can test my flow in CI against a multiple test data. something like this..

Comment: byte[] inputText = "s".getBytes();
        client.sendData(inputText, new HashMap<>(), "request");

        String responseClientData = client.getData("failure");
       Response response = gson.fromJson(responseClientData, Response.class);
        String responseFailure = (String) response.getAdditionalProperties().get("failure-reason");
        assertNotNull(responseFailure);
        assertThat(responseFailure, containsString(" something here "));
    }

Comment: You can use `GetFile` in place of `GenerateFlowFile` to read many test values in, or if you want to code something, export the flow as a template or use NiFi Registry to version it, and write a NiFi integration test to use a `TestRunner` to run the flow with known data and assert your expectations. There are many examples of this in the NiFi codebase. Look for files ending in `*IT.java`.